# UNION ALL vs CASE - SQL query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

> I need to retrieve the count of both *approved* and *unapproved* data from **my_table**.
> And I have tried both queries and succeeded. Which query is optimized and why. Please give suggestion

**DDL Query**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table( id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 approved TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
 invoice_no varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 deleted_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL)
```

First Query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN approved=1 THEN id END) as approved,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN approved=0 and deleted_at is null THEN id END) as unapproved
    FROM my_table
```

Second Query

```
 SELECT COUNT(id)
 FROM my_table
 WHERE approved=1 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(id)
 FROM my_table
 WHERE approved=0 and deleted_at is null
```

I have run command **explain extended** and attached the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Screenshots are discouraged here for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530)! Please edit your question and put in text instead of the images. If you can, you could upgrade to MySQL 8.20 - they have a new `EXPLAIN` which provides **far** more detail than the old version.

Comment: @Vérace Image is just for additional info.
All Queries are listed out

Comment: The two `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` outputs are the most important thing for answering the question. Can't you set the timing on and see which query completes quicker?

Comment: I do not see table's DDL - where is it?

Comment: Question edited. Added Table structure @Akina

Comment: Create index `(approved, deleted_at)`. Then use 2nd variant.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A -- no useful indexes:

Do the `CASE` approach.

Reason:  It is a single pass over the data.

PS:  `SUM(approved = 1)` is more concise, possibly faster.

Plan B -- useful indexes:

Do the `UNION ALL` approach if you have this composite index:

```
INDEX(approved, deleted_at)
```

and don't do `COUNT(id)`, instead do `COUNT(*)`.

That can be done in range scans on that one index.  The index is smaller than the table and each count only needs to scan part of the index.

Furthermore, `UNION ALL` is better optimized in 5.7 / 10.1.  So upgrade if you are not there yet.

Comment: Thank you, and why count(*) is preferred than count(id) @Rick James

Comment: *why `count(*)` is preferred than `count(id)`* `count(id)` checks each `id` value for NULL (and don't count if true) whereas `count(*)` ignores this. If `id` is NOT nullable than `count(*)` is more fast, else these expressions give different results.